# Content showing twice

Tags: layout, module, block, magento-1.9.1

I just created a module and I put this in my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <filteredproducts_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="filteredproducts/myblock" name="myblock" template="test.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </filteredproducts_index_index>
</layout>
```

Now for some reason, no mather what block I put there inside my reference name="content" tag. The block is shown twice.

test.phtml:

```
<?php
    echo "test";
?>
```

The text shown at the page is testtest. 
So the content must be loaded two times for some reason I just can't seem to figure out how.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the way you use "echo," though I'm afraid I can't offer tips.

Comment: No, that's not really the problem. Thanks for the answer tho.